# Can WKWebView play fairplay/drm protected videos?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, drm, fairplay

I want to play fairplay videos / DRM protected videos in `WKWebView` but couldn't find any solution except for playing them in `AVPlayer` or in `SFSafariViewControler`. Is there any way to do so or if not, is there any confirmation from Apple that `WKWebView` can't play those videos?

Comment: try to play https://bitmovin.com/demos/drm

Comment: @SahilManchanda, tried not working

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug fix to enable EME on WKWebView so it should be working now - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197964