# Unable to play fairplay protected video in wkWebView on iOS 12.4.6

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview, fairplay

I'm switching my Cordova App from the UIWebView to the WKWebView.

The app needs to play videos protected with the Fairplay DRM, and everything was fine with the UIWebView. When using the WKWebView I'm not able to play the videos on a iPad mini 2 with iOS 12.4.6.
The problem is that the window.WebKitMediaKeys object does not exist, while it shows up in the iPad emulator using iOS 13.x.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55896995/can-wkwebview-play-fairplay-drm-protected-videos) that there was a bug (already fixed) in the WKWebView, is it possible that the fix was not included in the latest iOS < 13 updates?